# Unable to receive push-push notifications for image/video messages using Twilio Programmable Chat

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, apple-push-notifications, twilio-programmable-chat

We are using Twilio SDK as a Chat feature within iOS app. Recently we have encountered an issue receiving push-notifications specifically for image and video "MessageKind" messsages, but messages of these kinds arrive just fine. Push-notifications arrive only for texts.

I have been going through "Push Notification Configuration" settings on Twilio Web Console, but there is nothing specifically that I can tune to enable push-notifications for image/video. New Messages are turned on.
Twilio SDK is version 4.0.0

[Push Notification Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3TTw.png)

Here is the function that is invoked for sending media messages:

```html
    private func sendMediaMessage(messageData: Data, mediaMessageType: MediaMessageType, completion: @escaping (Bool, String?) -> Void) {
        let inputStream = InputStream(data: messageData)
        let options = TCHMessageOptions()
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss-SSSS"
        
        switch mediaMessageType {
        case .photo:
            options.withMediaStream(inputStream,
                                    contentType: "image/jpeg",
                                    defaultFilename: formatter.string(from: Date()) + ".jpg",
                                    onStarted: {},
                                    onProgress: { (bytes) in },
                                    onCompleted:  { (mediaSid) in })
        case .video:
            options.withMediaStream(inputStream,
                                    contentType: "video/quicktime",
                                    defaultFilename: formatter.string(from: Date()) + ".mov",
                                    onStarted: {},
                                    onProgress: { (bytes) in },
                                    onCompleted: { (mediaSid) in })
        }
        
        self.sendTwilioMessage(messageOptions: options, completion: completion)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the information from Twilio support that Twilio Programmable Chat doesn't support push notifications for media messages for the time being.

There is a **workaround** though, although not very clean: Additionally to image/video messages send a text message with attributes, that contants push notification text, and use these attributes to determine that this text message has to be hidden from the user on both sides of the chat.